# mysql update 1 record based on Value of multiple other Records

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

SQL FIDDLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbebfb/1

I have a Parent Product in ProductTemp with SKU "Fruits & Nuts Gift Basket" Which has a ProductID = 1.

ProductId 1 "Fruits & Nuts Gift Basket", consists of 14 Child Products with ProductNo's(525,535,523,502,506,526,524,515,520,514,532,527,497,526) respectively.

If Any of the Child Product's (Fruits or Nuts) Quantity fall below the defined threshold (less than 3 for example) SET the "Fruits & Nuts Gift Basket", ProductID 1 Active state TO "0".

DESIRED RESULT: I want to disable the "Fruits & Nuts Gift Basket" if ANY of the Child Products are below the Threshold.

```
UPDATE ProductTemp
     SET Active = CASE
        WHEN (ProductNo) = (535) AND (Quantity < 3) THEN 0
        WHEN (ProductNo) = (525) AND (Quantity < 3) THEN 0
        WHEN (ProductNo) = (523) AND (Quantity < 2) THEN 0
        WHEN (ProductNo) = (526) AND (Quantity < 1) THEN 0
        WHEN (ProductNo) = (524) AND (Quantity < 1) THEN 0
        WHEN (ProductNo) = (502) AND (Quantity < 2) THEN 0
        WHEN (ProductNo) = (515) AND (Quantity < 1) THEN 0
        WHEN (ProductNo) = (506) AND (Quantity < 2) THEN 0
        WHEN (ProductNo) = (520) AND (Quantity < 1) THEN 0
        WHEN (ProductNo) = (514) AND (Quantity < 1) THEN 0
        WHEN (ProductNo) = (532) AND (Quantity < 1) THEN 0
        WHEN (ProductNo) = (527) AND (Quantity < 1) THEN 0
        WHEN (ProductNo) = (497) AND (Quantity < 1) THEN 0
        ELSE Active
      END
    WHERE ProductID = 1
```

I have also modified the restructured Query provided by @strawberry

`UPDATE ProductTemp 
    SET Active = CASE WHEN (ProductNo IN(535,525) AND Quantity < 3) 
        OR (ProductNo IN(523,502,506) AND Quantity < 2) 
        OR (ProductNo IN(526,524,515,520,514,532,527,497) AND Quantity < 1) 
        THEN 0 ELSE Active
    END
WHERE ProductID = 1;`

When running the above Query --- "0 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0"

Comment: Note that '3' is a string. 3 is an integer

Comment: I don't understand the condition. What condition is met? What's special about products 525 and 532? The condition isn't met for product 497, why doesn't that matter? Do you want to set product 1 to active = 0 if ANY of the WHEN conditions are met?

Comment: Thank You for the response, I see now that my condition could be taken vaguely. Lets say I have a Fruit Basket Product with Child products Apples, Oranges, Bananas and Kiwi fruit. If Bananas (525) and Kiwi (32) are out of stock, then I need to deactive the fruit basket product(1) . If any, ALL, OR 1 of the conditions are met then set Active = 0 in the Parent Product.

Comment: Why do you have what appears to be two 'id' columns, and how do we know which items belong to the hamper (and don't say "because I've told you"!)?

Comment: If I understand your question, you are asking why do I have "ProductID" and "ProductNo"?  ProductID is the Primary Key and AutoIncrement. Originally I had the WHERE Clause set to ProductNo but thought this might make the process easier to query off ProductID instead.

Comment: I have not been able to find the solution as of yet, any other input you have would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, I think your query can be rewritten as follows...

```
UPDATE my_table 
   SET active = CASE WHEN (ProductNo IN(535,525) AND Quantity < 3) 
                       OR (ProductNo IN(523,502,506) AND Quantity < 2) 
                       OR (ProductNo IN(526,524,515,520,514,532,527,497) AND Quantity < 1) 
                     THEN 0 ELSE active
                 END;
```

With reference to the comments below, and by way of illustration, consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(product_no INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,quantity INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (35,4),(525,2);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------------+----------+
| product_no | quantity |
+------------+----------+
|         35 |        4 |
|        525 |        2 |
+------------+----------+

SELECT *,(product_no IN(35,525) AND quantity < 3) x FROM my_table;
+------------+----------+---+
| product_no | quantity | x |
+------------+----------+---+
|         35 |        4 | 0 |
|        525 |        2 | 1 |
+------------+----------+---+
```

Comment: @ Strawberry -- It seems the logic you provide would only be true if for example ProductNo IN(535,525) AND Quantity < 3) were both less than 3? Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: I interpret this logic "(ProductNo IN(535,525) AND Quantity < 3)" as in order to be true productNo 535 and ProductNo 525 both need to be less than 3 in order to Set "Active" to 0?

Comment: No. IN() is equivalent to OR, not AND. (You could test this for yourself!) See edit

Comment: Thank you for the Illustration, completely logical. One variable to this problem which is missing from your original suggested query, the "WHERE" clause. I need to Set Active=0 WHEN the above conditions are met "WHERE" ProductNo = 1

Comment: `
UPDATE my_table 
   SET active = CASE WHEN (ProductNo IN(535,525) AND Quantity < 3) 
                       OR (ProductNo IN(523,502,506) AND Quantity < 2) 
                       OR (ProductNo IN(526,524,515,520,514,532,527,497) AND Quantity < 1) 
                     THEN 0 ELSE active
                 END
WHERE ProductNo = 1;
`

Comment: Yes. That bit doesn't make any sense :-(

Comment: I have a Parent Product called "Gift-basket" (ProductNo = 1) in the Product Table. Gift-basket consists of Child Products(14 in all) with ProductNo's(525,535,523,502,506,526,524,515,520,514,532,527,497,526) respectively. 

If Any of the Child Product's Quantities fall below a threshold (less than 3)

I need to SET the Gift-Basket Active state = 0 WHERE ProductNo = 1

Basically I want to disable the parent product if we can not fulfill the order because one or many of the child product have a low quantity...

Comment: The comments isn't the place for this. Amend your question accordingly. And, as always, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET. I find it's often best to start with a SELECT and then transform that into an UPDATE

Comment: Edited my original question / Post. Thank you for your continued assistance!

Comment: But, disappointingly, without including DDLs, sqlfiddle, or desired result set. :-(

Comment: Added SQL FIDDLE, Required Result, and consolidated post in above Edit.